# Weird behaviour of decimal.Round

Tags: c#, .net-core, coreclr

When using `decimal`, why the behaviour of rounding is always the same?

No matter if I use `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` or not it always gives `1.04`. In the first case, shouldn't the output be `1.03`?

```
Console.WriteLine(decimal.Round(1.035m, 2));
Console.WriteLine(decimal.Round(1.035m, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
```

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/664d98b3dc83a56e1e6454591c585cc6a8e19b78/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Decimal.cs#L612

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/61d792e202d039c304c4f04ad816a57688f32fd4/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Decimal.DecCalc.cs#L2429-L2444

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding) contain a helpful table demonstrating when the results of `ToEven` and `AwayFromZero` will be the same (and when they won't be). To round to `1.03`, it would need to round towards zero, which `Round` does not implement. (`Truncate` does, but that has no parameter for the decimals.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I get it now, `MidpointRounding.ToEven` will always try to round to even so in the case of `2.5` it will be 2 because 2 is even and not to 3 because 3 isn't even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[No:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.round?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Decimal_Round_System_Decimal_System_MidpointRounding_)

> This method [`Round(decimal d, int decimals)`] is equivalent to calling the `Round(Decimal, Int32, MidpointRounding)` method with a mode argument of `MidpointRounding.ToEven`.
>
> When d is exactly halfway between two rounded values, the result is the rounded value that has **an even digit in the far right decimal position**. For example, when rounded to two decimals, the value 2.345 becomes 2.34 and the value 2.355 becomes 2.36.

So when rounding `1.035` to even, it becomes `1.04` because 4 is even and 3 is not.

Answer (score 1):

The default rounding method is `MidpointRounding.ToEven`, so when choosing whether to round to either `1.03` or `1.04`, it chooses the one with the even number at the end, `1.04`.

Answer (score 0):

As the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/6be1edhb(v=vs.110).aspx) said:

```
public static decimal Round(
    decimal d,
    int decimals
)
```

> decimals : A value from 0 to 28 that specifies the number of decimal places to
>   round to.

You want to round at 2 places, it must 1.04

Answer (score 0):

This is seems expected behavior to me when rounding up a decimal.

Ex:

1.035 => 1.040 produce with two decimal place 1.04

1.033 => 1.030 produce with two decimal place 1.03

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the default rounding to round up? in this case the 5 gets rounded up and carried over...

By default, the Round method uses the rounding to nearest convention. The following table lists the overloads of the Round method and the rounding convention that each uses. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.2